# Error starting Guile with `readline` support

Tags: readline, guile, guix

I'm trying to configure Guile to use `readline`.

Here's my `~/.guile`:

```lisp
(use-modules (ice-9 readline))
```

(there was more, this one line is sufficient to have this failure)

Here's a log of my interaction:

```lisp
agam@ssdnodes-61de65ea00d0b:~$ guile
guile: warning: failed to install locale
Backtrace:
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
  1752:10 12 (with-exception-handler _ _ #:unwind? _ # _)
In unknown file:
          11 (apply-smob/0 #<thunk 7fb7984660c0>)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
    724:2 10 (call-with-prompt ("prompt") #<procedure 7fb796fc2e80 ?> ?)
In ice-9/eval.scm:
    619:8  9 (_ #(#(#<directory (guile-user) 7fb79846cc80>)))
In unknown file:
           8 (primitive-load "/home/agam/.guile")
In ice-9/eval.scm:
   721:20  7 (primitive-eval (use-modules (ice-9 readline)))
In ice-9/psyntax.scm:
  1230:36  6 (expand-top-sequence ((use-modules (ice-9 readline))) _ ?)
  1222:19  5 (parse _ (("placeholder" placeholder)) ((top) #(# # ?)) ?)
   259:10  4 (parse _ (("placeholder" placeholder)) (()) _ c&e (eval) ?)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
  3927:20  3 (process-use-modules _)
   222:17  2 (map1 (((ice-9 readline))))
  3928:31  1 (_ ((ice-9 readline)))
   3329:6  0 (resolve-interface (ice-9 readline) #:select _ #:hide _ ?)

ice-9/boot-9.scm:3329:6: In procedure resolve-interface:
no code for module (ice-9 readline)
```

If it helps, I'm doing this within Guile installed via `guix install guile`. I have installed `glibc-locales`, and `GUIX_LOCPATH` is set to `"$HOME/.guix-profile/lib/locale"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `locale ...` warning was a red herring, I was *missing* the `readline` package.

I needed to

- `guix install guile-readline`, followed by
- `. "$GUIX_PROFILE/etc/profile"`

After that, `guile` starts up fine.